# auto increment in excel for tens and thousands of records

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet having 1 million rows. I want to insert a new column and auto increment by 1.

So I did the following. filled in 1, 2 in successive rows and then
dragged it, but since it is a million rows i cannot possibly drag that too
long. Is there a formula to do the same, fill all the rows of the column
by auto incrementing by 1?

Comment: Can't you double click to autofill the column with a succesive number? 10 lakh = 100000 rows or something? Either way, you could also use PowerQuery and just simply add an index column.

Comment: Can you please expand so it will be useful to all

Comment: I meant; to fill a column I'd just double click the rightbottum indicator on a cell to autofill the rest of the column instead of dragging down.

Comment: OMG, that worked. I didnt know this little trick

Comment: Rest of the world doesn't use the word "lakh", so please don't use Indian words / measurements here.